# Tkinter Entry is 0 when i import the archive to other code

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Well, I'm a beginner.
I created a program with tkinter and for be organized I separate them in 3 secondary archives and 1 principal, all of them are .py, if they are executed separately they works, but when I import the secundaries to the principal code the entry it becomes in 0

Look:

```
from tkinter import *

def average_opt():
    import average


def necessarygrade_opt():
    import necessary_grade


def yourgrade_opt():
    import grade


root = Tk()
root.title('Average Calculator')
root.geometry('200x200')

# options for user
Button(root, text='Average', command=average_opt, width=20).place(x=25, y=30)
Button(root, text='Necessary Grade', command=necessarygrade_opt, width=20).place(x=25, y=90)
Button(root, text='Your Grade', command=yourgrade, width=20).place(x=25, y=150)

root.mainloop()
```

average is:

```
from tkinter import *

root2 = Tk()
root2.title('Average Calculator')
root2.geometry('400x400')


def calculate():
    average = (2 * grade1.get() + 2 * grade2.get() + grade3.get()) / 5
    Label(root2, text='Your average is {}'.format(average), font=('comic sans ms', 16, 'bold')).place(x=55, y=250)


# Labels: Show informations for user
grade1_label = Label(root2, text='Test 1 grade:', font=('comic sans ms', 13, 'bold')).place(x=35, y=30)
grade2_label = Label(root2, text='Test 2 grade:', font=('comic sans ms', 13, 'bold')).place(x=25, y=80)
grade3_label = Label(root2, text='Work's Grade:', font=('comic sans ms', 13, 'bold')).place(x=15, y=130)

# Entrys: Colect the informations from users
grade1 = IntVar()
grade2 = IntVar()
grade3 = IntVar()

grade1_entry = Entry(root2, textvariable=grade1, width=30).place(x=180, y=37)
grade2_entry = Entry(root2, textvariable=grade2, width=30).place(x=180, y=87)
grade3_entry = Entry(root2, textvariable=grade3, width=30).place(x=180, y=137)

# Buttons: Execute a command
Button(root2, text='Calculate', command=calculate, width=50).place(x=20, y=180)

root2.mainloop()
```

Necessary grade is:

```
from tkinter import *

root3 = Tk()
root3.title('Nota Necessária')
root3.geometry('400x400')


def calculate2():
    nota = (corrects.get() / total.get()) * 10
    Label(root3, text='Your grade was {}'.format(grade), font=('comic sans ms', 14, 'bold')).place(x=70, y=250)


# Labels: Show informations for user
escores_totais_label = Label(root3, text='Total:', font=('comic sans ms', 13, 'bold')).place(x=25, y=30)
escores_atingidos_label = Label(root3, text='Corrects:', font=('comic sans ms', 13, 'bold')).place(x=15, y=80)


# Entry: Colect the informations from users
total = IntVar()
corrects = IntVar()

escores_totais_entry = Entry(root3, textvariable=total, width=30).place(x=180, y=37)
escores_atingidos_entry = Entry(root3, textvariable=corrects, width=30).place(x=180, y=87)


# Buttons: Execute a command
Button(root3, text='Calculate', command=calculate2, width=50).place(x=20, y=180)

root3.mainloop()
```

Grade is:

```
from tkinter import *

root4 = Tk()
root4.title('Nota')
root4.geometry('400x400')


def calculate3():
    bimestral = (5 * target.get() - 2 * grade1.get() - grade2.get()) / 2
    Label(root4, text='The grade to arrive\in the average {} is {}'.format(target.get(), bimestral),
          font=('comic sans ms', 14, 'bold')).place(x=55, y=250)


# Labels: Show informations for user
grade1_label = Label(root4, text='Test 1:', font=('comic sans ms', 13, 'bold')).place(x=35, y=30)
grade2_label = Label(root4, text='Work's Grade:', font=('comic sans ms', 13, 'bold')).place(x=15, y=80)
target_label = Label(root4, text='Target Average:', font=('comic sans ms', 13, 'bold')).place(x=20, y=130)

# Entry: Colect the informations from users
grade1 = IntVar()
grade2 = IntVar()
target = IntVar()

grade1_entry = Entry(root4, textvariable=grade1, width=30).place(x=180, y=37)
grade2_entry = Entry(root4, textvariable=grade2, width=30).place(x=180, y=87)
target_entry = Entry(root4, textvariable=target, width=30).place(x=180, y=137)

# Buttons: Execute a command
Button(root4, text='Calculate', command=calculate3, width=50).place(x=20, y=180)

root4.mainloop()
```

I know it's very messy, it's because i lost myself in the middle of coding.
This is based in my school system, i don't know if others locations use it.

Thanks in advance.
(Sorry about my english LOL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can just change `root? = Tk()` to `root? = Toplevel()` and remove `root?.mainloop()` in the three module .py files.

You also need to fix the following issues:

In main, `command=yourgrade` should be `command=yourgrade_opt` for `Your Grade` button.

In `grade.py`, use `"` for the text of `grade2_label`: `text="Work's Grade:"`

In `average.py`, use `"` for the text of `grade3_label`: `text="Work's Grade:"`

In `calculate2()` inside `necessary_grade.py`, `.format(grade)` should be `.format(nota)`

Comment: some of the mistakes happened in the translation, because it was in my language

Answer (score 0):

You are creating instances of `Tk()` in all of your files. You must only create one<sup>1</sup> instance of `Tk()` for your entire program.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically you can do more than one, but you need a deep understanding of what happens when you do that. As a beginner you should consider it a hard and fast rule that you can only create one.